# Having signing issue when running react native ios app on physical device

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

I am having trouble in running react native ios app on physical device:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For installing the react-native app on your physical device, you should use Xcode!

So, open Xcode and press (Command +,) to go to preferences.

Then go to the Accounts tab and click on the + button, then click on Apple ID and sign in to your apple id.

After all of this follow the picture

[image]

On the fourth step, select your apple id and let apple sign your free development account.

If you got this error :

Failed to create provisioning profile.
The app ID "YourAppBundleID" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

you need to change your `Bundle Identifier` value, for example, add .ios in the end of your Bundle Identifier.

After signing you need to select your connected device from the select box beside play and stop button :-)

Also, you can set your build schema to Debug or Release mode.

For set your schema you have to press (Command + Shift +,), then click on play (run) button and then you can change Build Configuration there.

And finally click on play(build) button.